# VS Code Python unittest "No tests ran"

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up python unit tests in VS Code using unittest, and running into some issues.

I am able to run my tests by selecting Run Tests from the status bar, and by right-clicking my test file in Explorer.  When I do either of these, I see unit test output (e.g. "test_name ... ok" and "Ran 1 test in 0.002s") in the Python Test Log window, but I get a VS Code notification saying "No tests ran, please check the configuration settings for the tests."  I am also not seeing the Run Test | Debug Test code lens in the test file.

I have followed the setup instructions in the VS Code docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/unit-testing, but I'm wondering if there are other steps I'll need to follow to get proper integration with the IDE?

I am using VS Code version 1.12.1, on Windows.

Comment: Do the method names all begin with `test` ?

Comment: Yes, I copied the tests from the [unittest Basic Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) exactly to work with while setting this up.

Comment: Are you using VS Code `.1.21.1` or `1.12.1` like you typed? And you can try removing the test settings from your `.vscode/settings.json` and run the `Run All Unit Tests` command which will guide you through setting things up.

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in the test dir? If not, the `unittest` won't consider it as a test module then, would discover it.

Comment: @AnneThompson. did you resolve this? i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

See [unittest test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)

> Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible
>   with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages
>   (including namespace packages) importable from the top-level directory
>   of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid
>   identifiers).

I read the `unittest Basic Example` there is not something about make tests files to a module.
So that's Why you can see the `Run Test | Debug Test code lens in the test` **file**
But can't make test discovery discover it.

To make it to a module, you should create a `__init__.py` file in the same directory.

ps: for others who can't see `Run Test | Debug Test` code lens above the test, which means you can't make the `unittest` discover the single file as a test file.
Check the `-p` [pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-p) maybe the right move.